# What's the standard deviation of the difference between randomly paired data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, agreement-statistics, measurement

Assume that we want to compare the agreement of two methods of measuring blood pressure (e.g. a machine and a sphygmomanometer). In their [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10877-008-9127-y), Preiss & Fisher (2008) discuss the standard deviation of the difference between the two measurement methods, a quantity they call "precision". At the end of the paper, they state without derivation (slightly adapted):

> Since the precision of randomly paired data is $$ \mathrm{Precision} =
>  \sqrt{2}\,\dfrac{(SD_1 + SD_2)}{2} $$ where $SD_1$ and $SD_2$ are the
> standard deviations of the data collected from methods $1$ and $2$
> [...]

**Question:** How could this formula be derived as an approximation of the "true" (see below) precision?

I would expect the random pairing to break any correlation between the two measurements, leading to a standard deviation of the differences ("precision") of $\sqrt{SD_1^2 + SD_2^2}$.

The following simulation in `R` seems to agree with this:

```
library(mvtnorm)

set.seed(142857)

# Set up simulation
n <- 80
sdmat <- diag(c(15, 50)) # Different standard deviations
cormat <- matrix(c(1, 0.85, 0.85, 1), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE) # Correlation of 0.85
sigma <- sdmat%*%cormat%*%sdmat

x <- rmvnorm(n, mean = c(100, 100), sigma = sigma)

# Randomly pair data and calculate standard deviation of difference
res <- replicate(1e5, {
  sd(sample(x[, 2]) - x[, 1])
})

# Calculate average "precision" and by formulas
mean(res)
[1] 49.87843
sqrt(2)*(sd(x[, 1]) + sd(x[, 2]))/2 # From paper
[1] 44.06399
sqrt(var(x[, 1]) + var(x[, 2])) # Theory
[1] 49.89796
```

Comment: If the two methods are uncorrelated as a result of the "randomly paired data" I would expect the standard deviation of the differences to be $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2}$ and something much smaller of they were correctly paired (i.e. positively correlated).    Note $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2} \ge \sqrt{2}\frac{SD_1+SD_2}{2}$ but they are close if $SD_1\approx SD_2$

Comment: @Henry These are exactly my thoughts and simulations suggest the "precision" of randomly paired data is simply $\sqrt{SD_1^2 + SD_2^2}$. I'm still curious what's a possible explanation for their formula could be. Maybe it's simply an approximation if the standard deviations are close.

Comment: Doctors have a startling habit of using half-decent approximations and regarding them as statistical facts.  When I once saw the normal distribution described as a degree 3 polynomial I nearly fell off my chair, but it meant they could use a calculator and get surprisingly close.

Comment: @Henry there's no need to go after doctor's mathematical abilities; after all, they invented calculus https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/rediscovery-of-calculus-in-1994-what-should-have-happened-to-that-paper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Based on my comment:*

If the two methods are uncorrelated as a result of the "randomly paired data" I would expect the standard deviation of the differences to be $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2}$ (i.e. the square root of the variance of the difference) and something much smaller of they were correctly paired (i.e. positively correlated).

Note $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2} \ge \sqrt{2}\frac{SD_1+SD_2}{2}$ but they are close if $SD_1\approx SD_2$ so perhaps this is a doctor's approximation.  Meanwhile $\sqrt{SD_1^2+SD_2^2} \le SD_1+SD_2$  so it is never out by more than a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.